# issue with action bar, nothing happens

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have implemented an action bar, but when I am clicking on the icon nothing happens.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.tab1:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You touched setting button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        case R.id.tab2:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You touched Map button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; >
    <item android:id="@+id/tab1" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" android:title="@string/tab1" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/tab2" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_go_to_today" android:title="@string/tab1" android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the show() method on the toast object.
This should be like-

```
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You touched the settings button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```